# How to display datetime according to time zone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Now it is Melbourne time 5:30 PM. In LA it is 12:30 AM.

A database record is created at this moment. It has a "creation_datetime" time stamp.

When the customers at Melbourne look at the time stamp, I would like to display "**2016-07-04 17:30 (UTC+10:00)**". When customers at LA look at the time, I would like to display "**2016-07-04 00:30 (UTC-8:00)**".

Let's assume function "**getRecordTimeStamp(123)**" returns that time stamp as a **DateTime**, where "123" is the record ID. How do I generate "**2016-07-04 17:30 (UTC+10:00)**" and "**2016-07-04 00:30 (UTC-8:00)**" in C#?

Comment: Well what DateTime is returned? Is it a UTC timestamp? What have you tried so far? What sort of application is this, and how do you know the user's time zone?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utcTimeNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(now);

TimeZoneInfo melbourneTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time");
DateTime melbourneTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTimeNow, melbourneTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.", melbourneTime, melbourneTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(melbourneTime) ? melbourneTimeZone.DaylightName : melbourneTimeZone.StandardName);

TimeZoneInfo laTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime laTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTimeNow, laTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.", laTime, laTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(laTime) ? laTimeZone.DaylightName : laTimeZone.StandardName);


Console.ReadKey();
```